# Normal subgroup $N$ with $[G:N] = p$ and $p$ prime. Question on the centralizer.

Tags: group-theory

Given that $N \lhd G$ and $x \in N$, there are two cases. If $C_G(x) \nsubseteq N$ we have that the orbit $G(x) = \{gxg^{-1} \mid g \in G\}$ is equal to the orbit $N(x)$. If $C_G(x) \subseteq N$ then the orbit $G(x)$ is the union of $p$ orbits in $N$ with equal number of elements; in other words, there are $x_1,\cdots,x_p \in N$ so that $\displaystyle G(x) = \bigcup_{i=1}^p N(x_i)$.

How can I show that?

Comment: Please edit the condition $[G : N]=p$ into your question. Also if $p$ is prime, which I assume is the case, please indicate that too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In the first case, $C_G(x)\not\subseteq N$, if a normal subgroup has prime index, then it is maximal, so express $G$ as a product. When $y$ is conjugate to $x$ write the expression $y={}^gx$ in a different way.

When $C_G(x)\subseteq N$, consider the fact that $C_N(x)=C_G(x)$ and put it together with a different form of $C_G(x^g)$. Finally, what can be determined from examining the action of $N$ on $G(x)$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "express G as a product" ? and what means "$y={}^gx$ ?

Comment: By product, I mean look at a certain internal product $HN$, where $H$ is some subgroup and $N$ is some normal subgroup.

Comment: @André The notation ${}^gx$ is the conjugate $gxg^{-1}$.